# Conflicting inherited declaration warning in WebStorm for React lifecycle methods

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, webstorm

Every time on commit or code inspection in my `React` project in `WebStorm` i got warnings on `React` lifecycle methods like that:

`Warning:Conflicting inherited declaration React.ComponentLifecycle.componentDidMount was found in namespace internal`

I can only disable them on `Editor` -> `Inspections` -> `JavaScrip` -> `General` -> `Duplicate JavaScript declaration`. But this is really bad idea.

Is anyone got ideas how i can disable this outrageous warnings?

**Update**. Code snippet with warning message above:

```js
class Order extends React.Component {
    ...

    componentDidMount() {
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: can you see this warning shown in the editor? Please can you provide a code snippet that shows up the issue?

Comment: Lena, add snippet in Update.

Comment: can't recreate - no warning are shown for similar code (I'm using Webstorm 2017.2.3). Sample project I can use to replicate it would be helpful

Comment: Lena, no warnings if you make Code -> Inspect code for this file?

Comment: yes, exactly - no warnings reported for `componentDidMount()`

Comment: I get this too, but it's nothing to worry about - if anything, it serves the same purpose of `@Override` in Java. As long as your bundle compiles and your app runs, it's just something to ignore. On the plus side, it confirms you've typed the method name correctly :/

Comment: mwieczorek yes, bundle compiles but anyway i want to fix this annoying warnings.

Answer (score 7):

This seems to happen only when extending `React.Component`. If you import `Component` from `React` and extend that, the warnings go away.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Order extends Component {
  ...
}
```

Comment: With `React.Component` i got errors on `componentDidMount`, `componentWillUnmount` and `componentWillReceiveProps`. With `Component` only on `componentWillReceiveProps`. So this solution in only partial and require to rewrite a lot of code but not WebStorm settings :(.